# Cloud Functions: How to add extracted BigQuery data as a .csv attachment to a daily email?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am new to GCP Cloud Functions and Cloud Scheduler, and I am wanting to send a daily email at a specific time, which would send a BigQuery table extract - **attached to the email as a .csv file**.

I have written my Python code to query the data and send the email, but I am not sure how to add the extracted data as a `.csv` file attachment to the email.

So far, I have written the following Python function, which queries the data and sends the email, but I do not know how to actually write the code to attach the data as a `.csv` to the email:

```
def send_email_attachment(request):
    
    project_id = '[MY-PROJECT-ID]'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('[SERVICE-ACCOUNT-KEY]')

    client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id, credentials=credentials)

    query = '''
        SELECT *
        FROM `PROJECT_ID.DATASET.TABLE`
    '''

    results = client.query(query).result()

    message = Mail(
        to_emails="person@email.com",
        from_email=Email('steve-h@example.com', "Steve H."),
        subject="This is the data extract - attached",
        html_content=html_content
    )
    message.add_bcc("steve-h@example.com")

    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient('[API-KEY]')
        response = sg.send(message)
        return f"Email sent at {datetime.now()} with status code {response.status_code}"
    except HTTPError as e:
        return e.message
```

I feel like I am 75% of the way there, but it would be a great help if someone could help me with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code that should help you. Just one thing to note: the code reads opens a csv file and then attaches it.

```
        data = open(file_name, 'rb').read()
        base64_encoded_excel = base64.b64encode(data).decode('UTF-8')
        attachment = Attachment()
        attachment.file_content = base64_encoded_excel
        attachment.file_name = file_name.split("/")[-1]
        mail = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, html_content=html_content)
        mail.add_attachment(attachment)
```